# Маскировка доп. знаков разряда

Tags: java

```
//Маскировка доп. знаков разряда
Class Hexbyte {
    Static public void main (String arms[]){
        char hex[] ={
        '0','1'.'2','3','4','5','6','7'
        '8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f'

        };
        Byte b = (byte) 0xf1
        System.out.println("b=0x" + hex[(b>>4) & 0x0f] + hex[b&0x0f]);
    }
}

Result:b=0xf1
```

Comment: @manh, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Мне кажется, или идентичный вопрос был буквально вот в течение последней недели? Найти не смог.

Comment: @Etki так задания студентам дают одинаковые, или схожие)

Comment: @Elki дело в том, что я изучаю java самостоятельно и застрял на этом моменте уже 2 день(это я задавал этот вопрос позавчера), видимо, мой вопрос был удален. Поэтому я решил еще раз задать вопрос т.к.ответа так и не получил.

Comment: @DreamChild в общем если не трудно объясните,пожалуйста, почему в этом случае static стоит до public? и не могу никак понять значение b>>4 и действие над ним в System.out.println я буду очень признателен за помощь)

Comment: @manh гуглите про оператор сдвига и побитовую арифметику.

Answer (score 1):

Переведите все числа в двоичный вид и тогда все поймете.

0xf1 в двоичном представлении это 11110001. Сдвигаем его на 4 знака вправа (b>>4), получим 00001111. Получается, что этим действием мы "берем" из числа только старший байт(0xf).

Операцией b & 0x0f мы получаем младший байт, т.к. 0xf1 & 0x0f = 11110001 & 00001111 = 00000001

Comment: @Mashin Благодарю!
я разобрался, но можете еще объяснить почему static препозиционирует public? И как вы переводили 0хf1  получив 11110001(я когда сам пробовал еще, сразу преводил число 15 в двоичную-00001111- это и вызвало недоумения... 
ну, раз надоедать так надоедать) Последнее,что меня интересует:
Всегда ли нужно указывать символьный тип данных с массивом с символами в виде шестнадцатеричных переменных когда мы имеем дело с шестнацатеричными значениями? 
Вы извините за назойливость, уж больно много вопросов всплыло за последнее время)
Заранее благодарю!

Comment: 0xf1 это не 15, а 241. А вообще по вот этой таблице проще переводить http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/how-hex-to-binary.htm или любым инженерным калькулятором.

static можете записать и после public, думаю, нет никакой разницы.

Последний вопрос мне не очень понятен.

Comment: @Mashin понял, в общем,всегда ли нужно указывать все эти элементы массива с типом char?